# Counting During Recursion

Tags: objective-c, recursion

I'm having trouble with counting in a recursive operation. I'm creating a sitemap generator and I want to count the number of times each URL is linked. So far I'm having trouble counting higher than two! But at least it counts at all.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)parseURL:(NSURL*)URL
{
    NSLog(@"Parsing URL: %@", URL);
    // Check for URL in visited Array
    if ([self.visitedURLs containsObject:URL]) {

        NSLog(@"URL Already Visited...");

        // Add 1 to the count of links to this URL
        [[self.collectedURLs objectForKey:[URL absoluteString]] addToIncomingLinks];

        NSLog(@"Updating Link Count... (%d)", [[self.collectedURLs objectForKey:[URL absoluteString]] incomingLinks]);

        // Done parsing this URL, nothing else to do here...

    } else {

        ... Filter URLs and other stuff ...

        // Add URL as visited
        [self.visitedURLs addObject:URL];

        // Add filtered URL to Dictionary with link count of 1
        [self.collectedURLs setObject:[[OBAURLData alloc] init] forKey:workingURL];

        // Reload Table
        [self.crawlTableView reloadData];

        // parse found URLs
        [self parseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:workingURL]];
    }
}

// From the OBAURLData Object
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.incomingLinks = 1;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)addToIncomingLinks
{
    self.incomingLinks = self.incomingLinks + 1;
}
```

All of the code works as expected except the count doesn't go higher than 2 even though the NSLog statements all show the URLs as visited more than twice.

Could this be because of the recursion or am I just not seeing my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the difference between URL and workingURL in your else block, maybe you are recreating an instance of OBAURLData for each URL even if its the same?

I would print out how many times you are creating your OBAURLData objects.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I totally missed that. Each time the URL was found it was replacing the key/value pair in the dictionary. After adding a check for the key before adding it I am getting the results I expected. I wasn't even looking at that as a possible issue.

Comment: No worries Chris happy you fixed your issue :)